# Getting "License file is missing. Please activate Mono for Android." when deploying to emulator from VS2010

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm just starting with Mono for Android and installed it using the steps here http://mono-android.net/Installation/Visual_Studio and followed all the steps http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_World to create my Hello World abut I was not seeing anything, until I found this post to enable debug log http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Troubleshoot everything in the log seems to be ok except that I get the above error.

Here's the full log

-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:39 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\mandroid.exe
Arguments: -activated
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDERR] License file is missing.  Please activate Mono for Android.
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:40 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\mandroid.exe
Arguments: -activated
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDERR] License file is missing.  Please activate Mono for Android.
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:40 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDERR] 
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:40 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: devices
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] List of devices attached 
[STDOUT] 
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:42 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] 
[STDERR] 
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:42 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: devices
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] List of devices attached 
[STDOUT] 
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:43 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat
Arguments: list avd
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] Available Android Virtual Devices:
[STDOUT]     Name: MonoDroid
[STDOUT]     Path: C:\Users\Zubair.android\avd\MonoDroid.avd
[STDOUT]   Target: Android 2.2 (API level 8)
[STDOUT]     Skin: HVGA
[STDOUT]   Sdcard: 512M
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:44 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] 
[STDERR] 
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:44 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: devices
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] List of devices attached 
[STDOUT] 
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:45 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe
Arguments: -partition-size 512 -avd MonoDroid -prop monodroid.avdname=MonoDroid
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:46 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:46 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: devices
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] List of devices attached 
[STDOUT] emulator-5554  offline
[STDOUT] 
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:46 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: -s emulator-5554 shell getprop monodroid.avdname
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDERR] error: device offline
-- Process Still Running [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:52 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: start-server
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] 
[STDERR] 
-- Process Finished [5000] --
-- Starting Process - 5/20/2011 7:48:52 PM --
Executable: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
Arguments: devices
Appending Java path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
[STDOUT] List of devices attached 
[STDOUT]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I wasn't selecting the device after hitting Ctrl+F5, did it and it works, it does however take a while to deploy the files on the emulator and run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's your actual error.  I think that's a normal message for a machine that hasn't been activated.

Can you walk through what *does* happen, and tell us where something is happening that you are not expecting?